# What is the maximum number of words allowed in a MariaDB InnoDB Full Text Search query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I recieved this error when performing a search with 746 words (it wasn't intentional someone pasted text into the wrong box).

HA_ERR_FTS_TOO_MANY_WORDS_IN_PHRASE: Too many words in a FTS phrase or proximity search

The server is using MariaDB 10.2.14, what is the maximum limit? I couldn't find it in the MariaDB or MySQL docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 128.

I don't know yet if it's documented anywhere, but this from the [source](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/5abc79dd7ab2fccb4b05ca38a512ec816d2f8e52/storage/innobase/fts/fts0que.cc#L49):

```
/* Maximum number of words supported in a phrase or proximity search. */
#define MAX_PROXIMITY_ITEM  128
...
    if (num_token > MAX_PROXIMITY_ITEM) {
            query->error = DB_FTS_TOO_MANY_WORDS_IN_PHRASE;
            goto func_exit;
    }
```

A practical experiment supports that:

```
MariaDB [foo]> select match(name) against(concat('"', repeat('foo ', 128), '" @8')) from test;
...
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
MariaDB [foo]> select match(name) against(concat('"', repeat('foo ', 129), '" @8')) from test;
ERROR 191 (HY000): Too many words in a FTS phrase or proximity search
```